# Covering all colors with unit intervals

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, np-hard

Suppose we are given $n$ points on the real line, where each point is colored with a color from set $C=\{c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_k\}$ that contains $k$ distinct colors. We try to cover the $k$ distinct colors with as few unit length intervals as possible.

I think this problem is NP-hard and we can reduce from set cover problem. But I get stuck.

Also when $k=3$, is there a polynomial solution. I read [this link](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148597/minimum-number-of-intervals-to-cover-all-possible-colors?rq=1) but I can't understand his idea?

Comment: What is your question?  Please ask only one question per post.

Answer (score 5):

If $k$ is part of the input then the problem is NP-hard and you can indeed reduce from the set-cover problem.
Let $x_{1}, \dots, x_k$ be the items and $S_1, \dots, S_m$ be the sets.
Create a color for each item. Then, for each set $S_i$, create $|S_i|$ points on the real line at coordinates $2i +  \frac{1}{|S_i|}, 2i +  \frac{2}{|S_i|}, \dots, 2i +  1$. Color the $j$-th of such points with the color of the $j$-th item in $S_i$. Notice that: (i) one interval cannot cover two points from two sets, and (ii) all points from the same set can be covered with a single interval.

If $k$ is not part of the input then the problem is not NP-hard, unless P=NP. Indeed a trivial algorithm guesses one covered point for each color (there are only $O(n^k)$ guesses) and then covers the guessed points with the minimum number of intervals (this can be done via an easy greedy algorithm).